# R: n.restarts vs n.sim for function gosolnp() in Rsolnp package

Tags: r, optimization

What is the explanation of the 2 arguments in the function `gosolnp {Rsolnp}`: n.restarts & n.sim?

From the package writeup:

> n.restarts: The number of solver restarts required
>
> n.sim: The number of random parameters to generate for every restart
>   of the solver. Note  that  there  will  always  be  significant 
>   rejections  if  inequality  bounds  are present.  Also, this choice
>   should also be motivated by the width of the upper and lower bounds

From my understanding then, if I set `n.restarts=5` and `n.sim=10`, then for each `n.restart` it will generate `n.sim` starting points. Let's say I have no inequality constraints (so all random starting points are permissible), then I would have effectively rerun solnp $5 \times 10 = 50$ times.

Is that correct? Why then would I have these 2 arguments in the function and not just 1 where I could directly specify 50 reruns? This makes me think my understanding is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also got very confused by this. In the note  below the description of `gosolnp` in the documention, it also says:

> "Given a set of lower and upper bounds, the function generates, for those parameters not set as fixed,
>   random values [...] The resulting values are then sorted, and the best `N` (`N = random.restart`) parameter
>   vectors (corresponding to the best N objective function values) chosen in order to initialize the
>   solver."

So the way that `gosolnp` works is (someone correct me please if I am wrong):

1. Draw `n.sim * n.restart` random values from the parameter space and evaluate the objective function for each draw.
2. Take the best `n.restart` draws and run `solnp` with the respective draw as a starting value.

`n.restart` is therefore not redundant as it specifies how many times the solver is run in the second step.